# Division 16 persons into 4 groups

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways to divide 16 persons to 4 groups ? (there is no empty group) ?

I have two ideas, but I don't know what is ok:

Strirling number: $\{^{16}_{\ 4}\}$
or
${16\choose 4} \cdot  4^{12}$

Comment: You can rule out the ${16\choose4}\cdot4^{12}$ option as "obviously" wrong (and too large) because it can be interpreted as counting the number of ways to form four groups that have *leaders*.  I.e., you pick your four leaders in ${16\choose4}$ different ways, and then assign each of the remaining $12$ people to one of the four leaders in $4^{12}$ different ways.

Answer (score 3):

If the sets are possibly of different sizes, but non-empty, then the problem is canonical Stirling Number of the Second Kind. So the answer is $S(16,4)$.

For details, and recurrences that will help in the computation, please see the [Wikipedia article.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind)

**Remark:**  You may also be interested in a general classification of problems of this type, as described in [The Twelvefold Way.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelvefold_way)

Answer (score 0):

Take any 4 people, and put one of them in each group. This can be done in ${16\choose4}*4!$ ways. Now each of that initial choice of 4, the each rest of the 12 can be assigned in any of the 4 boxes, as in, in 4 possible ways, that is a total of $4^{12}$ ways.

Final answer is ${16\choose4}4! 4^{12}$

Comment: This answer counts the number of ways that you can form four groups that have *names* and *leaders*.  As such, it gives a number much larger than what the OP seems to be looking for.